# What is `yield resource if block_given?` in Devise::RegistrationsController#create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What is the purpose of `yield resource if block_given?` in `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`.

```
# POST /resource
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    set_minimum_password_length
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

I understand `resource` is the `@user` if you're using Devise to authenticate users, and that `yield` is used to render templates in an `html.erb` file.

But I don't understand what its doing in a controller, particularly when no blocks are explicitly being passed to it.